# Attach browser event to a control using XML-View

Tags: sapui5

My REST service send me a lot of data. Every property contains the `value` and a `help`-attribute that contains a long description of the field property.

Ok, I have data (a list of property with value and help) in a JSONModel and I use data-binding **XML** https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html to map data `value` in forms and tables.
Now I want show somehow `help` message for each property.

My idea is show a [message dialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/samples)  when the user double-click on the [Label](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Label.html) or on the [Text](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Text.html) of the column header in a table

Both Label and Text have [attachBrowserEvent](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#attachBrowserEvent) method but **I don't know how use the function to attach the event *wrinting only in the XML-views***

I would like something like this:

In XML-View:

```
<Label text="Language" 
          attachBrowserEvent:"function("click",showMessageHelp({model>/language/help}))">

<Input value="{model>/language/value}"/>
```

In the controller:

```
showMessageHelp:function(sMessage){

//show message dialog with sMessage
...........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a browser event for each label is possible but I can't find a way to do it without repeat each label id.

I have found an alternative solution: my data are shown in forms and tables. 
I have added on the right of each form couple of **label:** *value* a Text element with the help info:

```
    <Label text="Field duck"/>
    <Text text="{model>/elements/mainFields1/duck/value}"/>
    <Text text="{model>/elements/mainFields1/duck/ATTR/help/description}" visible="{ui>/bShowHelp}" />
```

In tables I have divided each column title in two group: header and **footer**; in the footer I have placed the help info:

```
<Column>
   <header>
      <Text text="Name"/>
   </header>
   <footer>
      <Text text="{model>/elements/airports/templateNewRow/name/ATTR/help/description}" visible="{ui>/bShowHelp}"/>
   </footer>
</Column>
```

I change the value of `bShowHelp` showing and hiding all help infos

Comment: But how do you control the visibility of help text?

actually how about using rich tooltip? this may not be good solution for mobile/touch screen but good for desktop..
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.RichTooltip.html

Comment: yes, tooltip isn't the right way if I want open the app in a mobile/touch context. My solution is good because 1)I can view at the same time all the helps and 2) I can hide and show the help by a button that change `bShowHelp` property in the model

Comment: oh ok.. I assumed that you wanted show help text only for a particular context at once :)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using **onAfterRendering** method.
Have CustomData in the XML:

```
<Label id="label" text="Language">
    <customData>
          <core:CustomData key="type" value="{/language/help}" />
    </customData>
</Label>
```

Then in controller use this customData:

```
  onAfterRendering: function () {
        var showValueHelp = function () {
            var text = this.getCustomData()[0].getValue();
            sap.m.MessageToast.show(text);
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        };

        this.byId("label").attachBrowserEvent("click", showValueHelp);
    }
```

[JS fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6s2up8k/)

PS:I am not sure this is viable solution for you.
This is the best I could come up with, currently.

Comment: I have the Label into a fragment (the main View have an IconTabBar with one fragment for each tab).
From the controller of the View I write `this.byId("label")` it returns `undefined`

Comment: I like your answer, but with your solution I must attach the browser event for each label !! :(